# Printing C array index contents from XCode debug console

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, audio, buffer

I am looking for a way to print the contents of a C style array index to the console window within XCode 4.5. In other words, when my audio buffer (a C array) is filled with float data, I put a breakpoint after it is filled and I want to just print values of contents within my array[]. I have tried the following:

```
// Just an example of what I'm doing. The following is a buffer that I am declaring:
int total = 235377;
float tmpArr[total];

// gives me the first index [0] contents value only when I type this in the console window in Xcode
p tmpArr

// gives the following error:
// error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
// error: 1 errors parsing expression
p tmpArr[3]

// gives me the address as expected
p &tmpArr

// the following seems to access contents but is casting them to ints and therefore truncating anything after the decimal...in audio programming, the float data is between 0 and 1 sooo....
frame variable -ffloat tmpArr
frame variable -ffloat tmpArr[3]
```

I have tried to find the answer as to why I am not able to access the contents of the array indexes. Am I missing something here? Do I have to place printf() within for loops every time I want to debug? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

As @Daniel Fischer points out, typing p *(tmpArr + indexNumber) in the XCode console successfully accesses tmpArr[indexNumber] and prints it to the debug console.

Comment: Have you tried `p *(tmpArr + 3)`?

Comment: Are you sure that's how you're declaring your array?  It sounds more like you've typed "float tmpArr(total)", from the debugger messages.

Comment: @DanielFischer that does the trick! Thanks for the pointer (literally...)